# Stored Javascript in MongoDB

Tags: php, javascript, mongodb

I am trying to store a query in MongoDB by using stored javascript.

It looks something like this right now:

```
$collection = $db->$app_id;

$query = $collection->find( $filterQuery );

$db->system->js->save(array(
    "_id" => "qo8qu0",
    "value" => new MongoCode("function() { return array($query) }")
));
```

Then I execute it:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($test = $db->execute("qo8qu0()"));
echo "</pre>";
```

However, I am getting this error:
`Catchable fatal error: Object of class MongoCursor could not be converted to string in /var/www/dev/classes/EmailMessaging.php on line 91`

Line 91 is this line (like above),
 `"value" => new MongoCode("function() { return array($filterQuery) }")`

If I use `count( $filterQuery );` instead of `find( $filterQuery );`
It works and returns the right number.

How can I make it work so it returns the array when using `find`?

Thank you

Comment: Just a question why are you trying to do this stuff through evaled javascript?

Comment: When users login, I want to run a query against their data, for example if they have over 10 friends, send an email. I don't necessarily know the fields in advance, as I am building this for others too. That's why I am trying to store queries.

Comment: Hmm I don't get your logic but ok, I mean you are basically doing in JavaScript what you would do in PHP....confuses me why

Comment: On my website, I can filter through my users' data and see it in a table, for example I can see people who are over 30 years old, who logged in the past 7 days. Then, what I am working on now is an 'email trigger', so every time someone who logs in matches this 'filter query' i just created, the specific email for that query will be sent to that user. Every time users login, I have to run them against the stored queries, and even sometimes as a cron job or something, because not all users will keep logging in, so I can send them an email if they haven't visited the site etc.

Comment: Wouldn't you just run a PHP cronjob pinging these queries against MongoDB from PHP? MongoDB has no "server-side" triggers or scheduling for this stuff to use the JS automatically, you will still need to use PHP for that

Comment: I'll check about it. Even if there would be a small delay for the mails to be send (cron timer), it might end up being more efficient.

Comment: It will be faster to do this in PHP only by the sounds of your scenario, using eval might harm your app

Comment: Yeah, I guess I can send the initial emails when the email is being created from the filter, and then create a cron job with PHP in which the queries could be ran every hour or something, and if new users match the filter, I run my mail function.

Comment: With the cron job, I still have the challenge of having the queries saved beforehand somehow, so that I can run these queries against the users every time the PHP script is ran.

Comment: You should already know the queries since you will need to pull the user out anyway, stored javascript would work the exact same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of evaluation of your code. It is evaluating this:

```
$query = $collection->find( $filterQuery );
```

So that `$query` is a `MongoCursor` and then you are attempting to concatenate that class into a string:

```
new MongoCode("function() { return array($query) }")
```

You need to do the entire thing witthin eval like so:

```
return $this->execute('function(){ return db.collection.find(filter); }',  array('filter'=>array('_id'=>1)));
```

`count` works because it returns an `int` which can be added to the string.

#### Edit

A way:

```
$db->system->js->save(array(
    "_id" => "qo8qu0",
    "value" => new MongoCode("function() { return db.collection.find(filter).toArray() }")
));
```

And then in your app:

```
$test = $db->execute("qo8qu0()", array('filter'=>array('_id'=>1)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm wondering though, how would I save the query before executing it?